# Prometheus Push Gateway

Tags: push, prometheus

I'm trying to set up a push gateway to connect to my Prometheus instance and I receive the following error...

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

Any ideas?

PS - I'm trying to connect using an `AWS instance` as I'm using an `RDP` (Windows)

Answer (score 0):

Too fewer pieces of information

If you have an application that needed to send data to Prometheus, you can use a pushgateway.

Usually is Prometheus reading metrics from your application, but, if you need to send the metrics you set up the pushgateway: the information will be sent on port 9091

Try to better describe your problem to get a more detailed help.